# Lightweight Prototype-based floating/resizable popup window

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

What's the best way to implement Meebo-style floating windows?  I'd prefer to use Prototype (but if there's a good Jquery implementation I'd be happy to look into it as well).  I'd like windows to be draggable/resizable and generally "lightweight" and responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out the [dialog component](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) in jQuery UI.  It is part of the official UI Library provided by jQuery.  Download the [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) and [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download) and then make sure you have references to both scripts in your page.  Then, it is as simple as calling dialog() on a jQuery object.  Check out the [dialog documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7.1/Dialog) for more information.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $("#dialog").dialog();
});
</script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See also: https://riversun.github.io/jsframe/ - is written in plain Javascript:

[image: screenshot example]